# Selected Option to none value is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a Select input field in html page.In a if block a condition should work.

```
<select id='selectopt'>
  <option value="">Select<option>
  <option value="1">1<option>
</select> 


<input type="text" id='text1'>



if($('#text1').val==='name'){
    $("#selectopt option[value='']").attr('selected', true);
}
else{
}
```

when i put this condition inside if its working in chrome and IE but not working in firefox..

Comment: why do you need the js when you can do `<option value="" selected>Select<option> `

Comment: @guradio May be this code is inside some event handler ?

Comment: @SureshAtta maybe unless OP gives additional information. we can only guess.

Comment: @SureshAtta I need the code to be worked inside an event

Comment: @NawazAhmed add all relevant code in OP which event and under what condition ?

Comment: use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`. also fix your condition. `$('#text1')==='name'` DOM element with not be equal to any text

Comment: @guradio .prop is working..i will mark correct if u answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

> Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched element.

```
$("#selectopt option[value='']").prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing a jquery object against a string

```
$('#text1') === 'name'
```

Maybe you want to compare the value of this object?

```
$('#text1').val() === 'name'
```

You could also simplify setting the dropdown value by:

$("#selectopt").val("")

Answer (score 0):

1. Match the if condition with value `$('#text1').val().trim()=== 'name'`
2. And  html syntax was wrong `</option>` tag not closing
3. Try with `prop()` instead of `attr()`

```js
if ($('#text1').val().trim()=== 'name') {
  $("#selectopt option:empty").prop('selected', true);
} else {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selectopt'>
  <option value="">Select<option>
  <option value="1">1<option>
</select>


<input type="text" id='text1' value="name">
```